# Can a missile retarget to the heat from the firing aircraft's engines?

Tags: military, missiles

I have heard that modern war planes utilize missiles which are directed to the heat of the enemy aircraft's engines.

Can a missile, shot by a fighter helicopter or jet, target the heat of the engines of the aircraft which fired it?

Comment: Not really since you have a missile lock before firing.

Comment: You mean, an accidental 'loop around', or something compared to radar targeting, where the reflection of the IR signature from the engines is reflected off the target?

Comment: Are you asking if a missle-launching aircraft can accidently shoot itself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_homing

Comment: @RonBeyer But what happens if a friendly aircraft happens to cross the missile "lock-path" when it's already in the air and chasing a target? Infrared missiles IMHO don't have IFF.

Comment: @jklingler I'm not completely sure, but you can be sure that it isn't the *shooter* aircraft, just another friendly, which isn't what the question is asking.

Comment: The fly time of a missile from a MANPAD is a few seconds... there is no time for that.

Comment: Not sure about a missile, but an F11F pilot managed to [shoot himself down](http://www.aerofiles.com/tiger-tail.html) with his 20mm cannon

Comment: @RonBeyer - `Not really since you have a missile lock before firing` - Not always. See: [LOAL (lock-on after launch)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-on_after_launch)